# I have a react app that should render the child component card on click. When trying to pass the child down from the parent, the parent breaks

Tags: reactjs

I'm also using semantic-ui-react. When I pass the child component down from the parent the css styling gets all messed up, I lose my images and the click doesn't work.

I can call the cardClickHandler method in the parent component and am console logging the correct child, i just can't get it to render (am not hitting the console.log in the child component).

I also tried to run the cardClickHandler method in the images container to pass it down but that didn't work.

please help and explain what i'm doing wrong. thanks!

images container:

```
import React from 'react';
import SearchBar from '../components/SearchBar';
import Images from '../components/Images';
import ImageCard from '../components/ImageCard';

class ImagesContainer extends React.Component {
    state = {
        images: [],
        image: {},
        sortValue: '',
        inputValue: '',
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/images').then((resp) => resp.json()).then((resp) => {
            this.setState({
                images: resp
            });
        });
    }
    
    imageFilterOnChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            inputValue: event.target.value
        });
    };

    sortImages = (images) => {
        if (this.state.sortValue === 'location') {
            return [ ...images ].sort((a, b) => {
                if (a.location > b.location) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (a.location < b.location) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            });
        } else {
            return images;
        }
    };


    render() {
        const filteredImages = this.state.images.filter((image) => {
            return image.location.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.inputValue.toLowerCase());
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <Images
                    images={this.sortImages(filteredImages)}
                    onClick={this.cardClickHandler}
                />
            
                    <SearchBar
                        images={this.sortImages(filteredImages)}
                        imageFilterOnChange={this.imageFilterOnChange}
                        inputValue={this.state.inputValue}
                        onChange={this.handleSortImages}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ImagesContainer;
```

parent component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ImageCard from './ImageCard';
import { Card, Image } from 'semantic-ui-react';

class Images extends React.Component {
    state = {
        image: []
    };

    cardClickHandler = (e) => {
        let cardId = e.target.dataset.id;
        this.props.images.find((image) => {
            return image.id === cardId;
        });
        console.log('hi, cardId', cardId);
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/images/${cardId}`)
            .then((resp) => resp.json())
            .then((resp) => {
                this.setState({
                    image: resp
                })
                console.log(this.state.image);
            })
    }

    render() {
        const allImages = this.props.images;

        return allImages.map((image) => {
            return (
                <Card
                    key={image.id}
                    className="photo"
                    data-id={image.id}
                    data-name={image.name}
                    onClick={this.cardClickHandler}
                >
                    <img
                        src={image.image}
                        alt=""
                        data-id={image.id}
                        data-name={image.name}
                        className="photo-image"
                        height={265}
                    />
                </Card>
            );
        });
    }
}

export default Images;
```

child component:
i'm not hitting the console.log here, so no more code!

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, Image } from 'semantic-ui-react';

class ImageCard extends React.Component {

    render() {
        console.log('image card');
        return (
            <Card>
                
            </Card>
        );
    }
}
export default ImageCard;
```

Comment: You have an extra `</div>` in your ImagesContainer. Also, you'll want to remove `onClick={this.cardClickHandler}` from ImagesContainer as `cardClickHandler` is defined not on ImagesContainer but instead on your Images component.

Answer (score 0):

I left a comment with a few improvements to the code you could make.  Specifically:

- You have an extra `</div>` in your ImagesContainer.
- Also, you'll want to remove `onClick={this.cardClickHandler}` from ImagesContainer as `cardClickHandler` is defined not on ImagesContainer but instead on your Images component.

But the problem is that you are not rendering your `ImageCard` component at all. You are just rendering `<Card>` instead of `<ImageCard>`

Specifically, your parent component's render should change from this:

```
render() {
    const allImages = this.props.images;

    return allImages.map((image) => {
        return (
            <Card
                key={image.id}
                className="photo"
                data-id={image.id}
                data-name={image.name}
                onClick={this.cardClickHandler}
            >
                <img
                    src={image.image}
                    alt=""
                    data-id={image.id}
                    data-name={image.name}
                    className="photo-image"
                    height={265}
                />
            </Card>
        );
    });
}
```

to this:

```
render() {
    const allImages = this.props.images;

    return allImages.map((image) => {
        return (
            <ImageCard
                key={image.id}
                className="photo"
                data-id={image.id}
                data-name={image.name}
                onClick={this.cardClickHandler}
            >
                <img
                    src={image.image}
                    alt=""
                    data-id={image.id}
                    data-name={image.name}
                    className="photo-image"
                    height={265}
                />
            </ImageCard>
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks! I understand that i'm not passing <ImageCard>, because when i do, my css/grid gets all messed up. But i guess tHaTs where my problem is, semantic-ui-react and css...

Comment: Yes. you have to render ImageCard in order for any of the code within the ImageCard component (like your console.log) to run